# How to use fully formed SQL with spark structured streaming

Tags: scala, apache-spark, spark-structured-streaming

Documentation for Spark structured streaming says that - as of spark 2.3 all methods on the spark context available for *static* `DataFrame`/`DataSet`'s are also available for use with *structured streaming* `DataFrame`/`DataSet`'s as well.   However I have yet to run across any *examples* of same.

Using fully formed SQL's is more flexible, expressive, and productive for me than the `DSL`. In addition for my use case those SQL's are already developed and well tested for *static* versions. There *must* be *some* rework - in particular to use `join`s in place of `correlated subqueries`. However there is still much value in retaining the overall full-bodied sql structure.

The format for which I am looking to use is like this hypothetical join:

```
 val tabaDf = spark.readStream(..)
 val tabbDf = spark.readStream(..)

 val joinSql = """select a.*, 
                  b.productName 
                  from taba
                  join tabb 
                  on a.productId = b.productId
                  where ..
                  group by ..
                  having ..
                  order by .."""
 val joinedStreamingDf = spark.sql(joinSql)
```

There are a couple of items that are not clear how to do:

- Are the `tabaDf` and `tabbDf` supposed to be defined via `spark.readStream`: this is my assumption
- How to declare `taba` and `tabb` . Trying to use

  ```
  tabaDf.createOrReplaceTempView("taba")
  tabbDf.createOrReplaceTempView("tabb")
  ```

  results in

  > WARN ObjectStore: Failed to get database global_temp, returning NoSuchObjectException

All of the examples I could find are  using the `DSL` and/or the `selectExpr()` - like the following https://databricks.com/blog/2017/04/26/processing-data-in-apache-kafka-with-structured-streaming-in-apache-spark-2-2.html

```
 df.selectExpr("CAST(userId AS STRING) AS key", "to_json(struct(*)) AS value")
```

or using `select` :

```
sightingLoc
  .groupBy("zip_code", window("start_time", "1 hour"))
  .count()
  .select( 
    to_json(struct("zip_code", "window")).alias("key"),
    col("count").cast("string").alias("value"))
```

Are those truly the only options - so that the documentation saying that *all* methods supported on the `static` dataframe/datasets are not really accurate?   Otherwise: aAny pointers on how to correct the above issue(s) and use straight-up `sql` with streaming would be appreciated.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The streams need to be registered as temporary views using `createOrReplaceTempView`. AFAIK `createOrReplaceView` is not a part of the Spark API (perhaps you have something that provides an implicit conversions to a class with such method).

```
spark.readStream(..).createOrReplaceTempView("taba")
spark.readStream(..).createOrReplaceTempView("tabb")
```

Now the views can be accessed using pure SQL. For example, to print the output to console:

```
spark
  .sql(joinSql)
  .writeStream
  .format("console")
  .start()
  .awaitTermination()
```

Edit: After question edit, I don't see anything wrong with your code. Here is a minimal working example. Assuming a test file `/tmp/foo/foo.csv`

```
"a",1
"b",2
```

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.types._
val schema = StructType(Array(StructField("s", StringType), StructField("i", IntegerType)))
spark.readStream
  .schema(schema)
  .csv("/tmp/foo")
  .createOrReplaceTempView("df1")
spark.readStream
  .schema(schema)
  .csv("/tmp/foo")
  .createOrReplaceTempView("df2")

spark.sql("SELECT * FROM df1 JOIN df2 USING (s)")
  .writeStream
  .format("console")
  .start()
  .awaitTermination()
```

outputs

```
-------------------------------------------
Batch: 0
-------------------------------------------
+---+---+---+
|  s|  i|  i|
+---+---+---+
|  b|  2|  2|
|  a|  1|  1|
+---+---+---+
```

Comment: Hi Ollik - maybe you missed from the question : registering the views are included already `tabaDf.createOrReplaceView("taba")` and `tabbDf.createOrReplaceView("tabb")` .  And then `spark.sql(joinSql)` . Your answer has not added any new code. Do you have something similar to this structure actually working - and if so a sscce would be great

Comment: In particular - there is no mention here about how to fix the `WARN ObjectStore: Failed to get database global_temp, returning NoSuchObjectException`

Comment: @javadba So in your snippet `createOrReplaceView` was used instead of `createOrReplaceTempView`. Note the *Temp* part. Tried that the snippet works

Comment: That was a typo . My actual code used/uses `createOrReplaceTempView`.  But are you saying you have this working?  I have a commitment for next 2.5 hours. In the meantime i'll upvote and then get back to running the code again at that time. I'd really like to see this working and to award:  will see at that time.

Comment: Added a minimal example to the answer to demonstrate it works

Comment: Dude you're awesome.  I wonder why it is that you're not encountering  that `WARN`(/issue) that I am:  `WARN ObjectStore: Failed to get database global_temp, returning NoSuchObjectException`.  The same code is successful in  registration with your in-memory catalog whereas it does ***not*** work in my environment. If you have any thoughts on that ..   I'm going to award in the meantime but any further insights on how/why you're getting better results than me would be much appreciated

Comment: After `readStream` do you use any persistence mechanisms such as `load()` and/or `cache()` ?

Comment: @javadba It seems the exception is related to Hive https://github.com/apache/hive/blob/master/standalone-metastore/metastore-server/src/main/java/org/apache/hadoop/hive/metastore/ObjectStore.java#L727 so I assume you are using hive context? Maybe the issue is in the metastore configuration. Haven't been using that myself but here's a good tutorial for that https://jaceklaskowski.gitbooks.io/mastering-spark-sql/spark-sql-hive-metastore.html

Comment: No, no _hive_ here.  This is a real problem for me.